# Monkey Patch Date class the best option?

Tags: ruby, date, model, monkeypatching

In my app, I want to support a blank date field as meaning "some indefinite date in the future", both upon entry and viewing.  Since I'm storing this in the database and nil sorts before any non-nil date, I decided to monkey-patch the Date class to implement a "max_value" method that returns "1/1/10000" (the date I picked to represent an indefinite date in the future).  I have been overloading +, -, to_s, and other operators/methods to behave appropriately with this value.  I then added a before_save callback to the model to convert any blank dates to Date.max_value.  This all seems to work (with the exception of a few bugs I'm trying to work out), but is there a better way to do this without monkey-patching the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you are looking for is *null*. Overriding a base class, like Date is just begging for trouble down the road.

Do it in the query

```
SELECT * FROM Mystery_Events ORDER BY ISNULL(some_event_date,'1/1/10000') ASC
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
ORDER BY (case WHEN some_event_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), some_event_date, some_other_sorting_field_to_give_order_to_the_nulls ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I don't disagree with you one bit.  I got bitten a number of times when trying to monkey-patch, and eventually hit one that I couldn't figure out how to get around.  I kinda knew it was a bad idea, which is why I asked the question, to hear some other approaches.  It was, however, an enlightening experience overall.

Comment: I did, however, leave in a couple overrides for the yesterday and tomorrow methods.  I discovered that they seem to generate the wrong value late in the day -- I suspect that there is some time-zone issue, like they are generating UTC values instead of local values.

Comment: i always thought yesterday/tomarrow was just short hand for +/- 24 hours... is this not true?

Comment: @colinross I believe that you are correct, but I think something is lost in the translation and they are somehow returning the date in UTC instead of local time, which makes it incorrect in the evening here (offset 8 hours).

Comment: @Jack R-G, That sounds like a bug if the methods are silently converting the timezone. You should introduce a topic on the ruby-core mailing list with an example of the mischievous behavior... I would think that methods should not implicitly be changing timezones...